# Days calculation between events in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table in MS SQL looks like below:

```
CLIENT | CONTACT_DATE | WAY_CONTACT
-------------------------------------
123    | 2021-01-01   | phone
123    | 2021-01-10   | phone !
123    | 2021-01-11   | phone !
123    | 2021-04-05   | mail !
123    | 2021-04-06   | mail !
555    | 2021-11-02   | mail !
555    | 2021-11-03   | mail !
555    | 2021-11-05   | phone
```

By "!" I signed moments where particular client has been cotacted more often than even 5 days by way_contact.

And I would like to calculate how many time a particular is situation where CONTACT_DATE is more often than every 5 days, so as a result I need something like below:

```
WAY_CONTACT | CONTACT_MORE_OFTEN_THAN_EVERY_5_DAYS
------------------------------------------------------
phone       | 1
mail        | 2
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: good question, Management Studio 17 ? I think one of the latest :)

Comment: Nathan_Sav I checked it by select @@version - and it is Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Comment: Squirrel, definitely no! probably you did not read question :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like so:

```
select
    q.way_contact,
    sum(q.p)
from
    (select 
         t.way_contact,
         case 
             when datediff("d", 
                           lag(t.contact_date) over (partition by t.client, t.way_contact
                                                     order by t.client, t.way_contact, t.contact_date),
                           t.contact_date) <= 5 
                 then 1 else 0 
         end as p
     from 
         tblContact as t) as q
group by 
    q.way_contact
order by 
    q.way_contact
```

[image]

Comment: But where is in above code number "5" means number of days how many days you want the communication to be every ??

Comment: @evn11  Apologies, i've added

Comment: Nathan, so to be sure on 100% - your code answer on the question: How often in a given contact channel (WAY_CONTACT) does it occur that a particular customer is contacted more often than every 5 days, correct?

Comment: It doesnt show for a particular customer as the data shown/question didnt really state that.  It shows across all clients

Comment: Ok, but for example in CLIENT A we had 2 times communication by phone in less than ecery 5 days, in CLIENT B we had 1 time communication by phone in less than every 5 days, so as I mean using your code we will have in sum 3 in column "CONTACT_MORE_OFTEN_THAN_EVERY_5_DAYS"? yes ?

Comment: Nathan could you tell me in your words what result gives your code based on my data ? :=) please

Comment: The number of contacts witihin a 5 day gap per client totalled,  So in your data 123 has 2 mails and 2 calls within 5 days 555 just has 2 mails, so output is as desired in question

Comment: Great! so it was 100% what I wanted! Thank you very much :) I gave best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's solution that uses a calculated rank for the within 5 days.

> ```
> SELECT WAY_CONTACT
> , SUM(CEILING(1.0*Days/5)) AS CONTACT_MORE_OFTEN_THAN_EVERY_5_DAYS
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT CLIENT, WAY_CONTACT, Rnk
>     , DATEDIFF(day, MIN(CONTACT_DATE), MAX(CONTACT_DATE)) AS Days
>     FROM
>     (
>         SELECT *
>         , [Rnk] = SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT, WAY_CONTACT ORDER BY CONTACT_DATE)
>         FROM
>         (
>             SELECT *
>             , [flag] = IIF(5 >= DATEDIFF(day, 
>                 LAG(CONTACT_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT, WAY_CONTACT ORDER BY CONTACT_DATE), 
>                 CONTACT_DATE), 0, 1)
>             FROM CLIENT_COMMUNICATIONS
>         ) q1
>     ) q2
>     GROUP BY CLIENT, WAY_CONTACT, Rnk
>     HAVING MIN(CONTACT_DATE) < MAX(CONTACT_DATE)
> ) q3
> GROUP BY WAY_CONTACT
> ORDER BY WAY_CONTACT;
> ```

> 

| WAY_CONTACT | CONTACT_MORE_OFTEN_THAN_EVERY_5_DAYS |
| --- | --- |
| mail | 2 |
| phone | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=32a99c50b9539311c2b0c27c29819e80)*